# How can i add image and background color?

Tags: html, css

```css
.banner-logo-container {
    
    padding-top: 37px;
    padding-bottom: 37px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.banner-logo-container .banner-holder {
    max-width: 1180px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.banner-logo-container .form-content{
  width: 590px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 19px;
    padding-bottom: 600px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color:red;
}


.banner-logo-container .form-content form{
    float: righr;
}

.banner-logo-container .logo-content {
    width: 590px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 19px;
    padding-bottom: 600px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #0b224b;
}
```

```html
  <html>
     <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
     </head>

     <body>
   <div class="banner-logo-container">
        <div class="banner-holder">
            <div class="form-content">
        
                <form>
                    <label>Contact Us</label>
                    <label>Bold labels are required</label>
                    <input type="text" value="name">
                    <input type="email" value="Email Address">
                    <input type="text" value="Phone">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="logo-content">
               Logo
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VDE8.png)

How can I add image and background color( both should occupy50% and 50% of the web page)? There should be a form on the image and logo titles on bg color. The form and the logo should be inside `max-width:1180`. Contact should float right of the image and logo should float to the left of the bg color. I'm trying to do this for three hours. Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Put some code so we'll be able to help you

Comment: please add your code here.

Comment: @mayankjain Please Check it

Comment: @LucasTambarin Tambarin Please check it

Comment: the code snippet is running properly. the contact is at the right and  the logo at the left. What is the issue then? @ravan one

Comment: @mayankjain open in full screen. I want bg color to occupy complete width.The form and the logo should have max width of 1180. I nee something similar to bootstrap col. When i reduce the screen size the log part should move down

Comment: I need form and my  logo to be at center of the page so i made 1180 as my max width

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small code pen to help you to start.
I am using flex box and setting the width of both container div to 50%, so each div is taking half of the screen.
Now you just have to change background and put your elements as you want on the code pen.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">
    test1
  </div>
  <div class="div2">   
    test2
  </div>
</div>

.container{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.div1{
  background:green;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
}

.div2{
  background:red;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/kelinox/pen/ZoEKRa